# Rotating Image Continuously depending on action

Tags: vb.net

How to rotate the image on any action and close it, if the action complets. Example would be like syncing image.

Comment: You better use a GIF...

Comment: i Dont want to use GIF as i would require many images to make it look like GIF.Are their any alternative??

Comment: Take a look at this: http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/171064/how-to-rotate-a-picture-image-in-VB-NET

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are using a `picturebox` to hold your `image`, If so you could use the following code to `rotate` your `image`,

```
    'I just used a while loop here for testing purpose only, you can use a timer
    'for rotating your image smoothly. By the way, stop and start the timer
    'according to your need.
    While True
        PictureBox1.Image.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone)
        PictureBox1.Refresh()
    End While
```

### [RotateFlip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/system.drawing.image.rotateflip.aspx)